# Can I use Wake on LAN with a Ethernet to WiFi adapter?

Tags: windows, wake-on-lan, adapter

Can I use Wake on LAN with an Ethernet to WiFi adapter? I am not really sure if it would work. I couldn't find this question anywhere else. Power isn't an issue BTW. Here is the adapter I have [https://www.amazon.com/IOGEAR-Universal-Ethernet-Adapter-GWU627/dp/B004UAKCS6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004UAKCS6)

Comment: You told us nothing about your adapter

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/IOGEAR-Universal-Ethernet-Adapter-GWU627/dp/B004UAKCS6 Is the one I would use

Comment: When you go into the properties for the adaptor.  Are you able to enable Wake On Lan?

Answer (score 0):

In Device Manager, expand Network Adapters section and locate yor network adapter, right click it and choose properties. It will display the network adapter’s properties.
In the Network Adapter’s properties, go to Advanced tab and locate the network adapter’s option to check
Go to the Power Management tab, and check the settings, allow this device to wake the computer